# Perl + PostgreSQL-- Selective Column to Row Transpose

Tags: perl, postgresql

I'm trying to find a way to use Perl to further process a PostgreSQL output. If there's a better way to do this via PostgreSQL, please let me know. I basically need to choose certain columns (Realtime, Value) in a file to concatenate certains columns to create a row while keeping ID and CAT.

First time posting, so please let me know if I missed anything.

Input:

```
ID  CAT   Realtime  Value
A   1    time1       55
A   1    time2       57
B   1    time3       75
C   2    time4       60
C   3    time5       66
C   3    time6       67
```

Output:

```
ID  CAT  Time                   Values
A   1    time 1,time2           55,57
B   1    time3                  75
C   2    time4                  60
C   3    time5,time6            66,67
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this most simply in Postgres like so (using array columns)

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE output AS SELECT
  id, cat, ARRAY_AGG(realtime) as time, ARRAY_AGG(value) as values
  FROM input GROUP BY id, cat;
```

Then select whatever you want out of the output table.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it very well with no errors due to realtime and value being non-string fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id
     , cat
     , string_agg(realtime, ',') AS realtimes
     , string_agg(value, ',') AS values
FROM   input
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

[`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) requires PostgreSQL 9.0 or later and concatenates all values to a delimiter-separated string - while `array_agg()` (v8.4+) creates am array out of the input values.

---

About **`1, 2`** - I quote the manual on the `SELECT` command:

[`GROUP BY` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

> expression can be an input column name, or the name or **ordinal number**
>   of an output column (SELECT list item), or ...

[`ORDER BY` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY)

> Each expression can be the name or **ordinal number** of an output column
>   (SELECT list item), or

Emphasis mine. So that's just notational convenience. Especially handy with complex expressions in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: 1, 2 stand for "1st and 2nd columns" in the current select? Tnx

Comment: Thank you! I upgraded to 9.1 when I realized part of the issue was the need for an upgrade. The system I inherited had 8.3. Words wonderfully.

Comment: @CornelGhiban: I added a bit about `1, 2` to my answer.