# Formatting to Timestamps to Interval

Tags: r, postgresql, matlab, time, weka

I have input data that consists of a list of subject id's and 2 categories, as well as a realtime and two values. The realtime and values for each ID may be of varying lengths. There are multiple ID's in the file, and multiple categories for each ID.

I'm having some trouble finding a good tool to do this change of change to a data file. I am using PostgreSQL to extract the data and R for analysis for can't find a good function for either to help. Any thoughts? I essentially want to make the realtime into 30 min intervals rather than timesptamps and use those as my attributes and the values from V1 as the actual values. But first, I must get the time interval categories into my data.

Input:

```
ID  CAT1    CAT2    realtime        V1  
21  23      51      11/2/3138 18:29 135
21  23      51      11/2/3138 18:58 132
21  23      51      11/2/3138 21:05 129
21  23      51      11/2/3138 21:05 130
21  23      51      11/2/3138 22:53 142
71  23      52      11/4/3138 6:47  66
71  23      52      11/4/3138 8:45  69
71  23      52      11/4/3138 8:45  68
```

Output:

```
ID || CAT1 || CAT2 || Interval 0 || Interval 1 || Interval 2 || Interval 3 || ...
21 || 21   || 23   ||  135       || 132        || 130        || 142        || ...
71 || 23   || 52   || 66         || 69         || 68         || NULL       || ...
```

I also wrote something about concatenating the data, which hasn't shown to be very useful, but if you disagree please let me know: [Perl + PostgreSQL-- Selective Column to Row Transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958728/perl-postgresql-selective-column-to-row-transpose/8963329#8963329)

EDIT:: I would be open to using Weka or Matlab if this exists -- or a scripting language to figure this out, but I'm hoping there's a function/package somewhere out there...

Comment: 3138? Are you sure about that?

Comment: It's public health data, so it gives junk years. Since I'm only interested in the time intervals, we don't need to focus on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply convert the "realtime" strings into actual time, and then work from there, e.g. by  dividing by the interval length:

```
d$interval = floor(as.numeric(strptime(d$realtime,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))/1800)
```

if you want literally a variable with "Interval x" simply add

```
d$interval = paste("Interval", d$interval - min(d$interval))
```

and to create a long format from that, use `reshape`:

```
reshape(d[,names(d) != 'realtime'],idvar=c("ID","CAT1","CAT2"),timevar="interval",direction="wide")
```

Note, however, that the default is to take the first matching value in case of duplicates, whereas in your example I think you are using the last one, so you may want to reverse the order of your data if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

To insert timestamps in a **PostgreSQL** table in non-standard format you can use the function [`to_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE).
Example:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('11/2/3138 18:29', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh24:mi')
```

Result (display in ISO 8601 format):

```
3138-11-02 18:29:00+01
```

---

To truncate timestamps to half hour precision, you could use the functions[`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) and [`date_part()` or `extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE).
Example:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', now())
     + CASE WHEN extract(minute from now()) > 29 THEN 30
                                         ELSE 0  END * interval '1 min'
```

Comment: This date_trunc is something I didn't know before, thank you. I was wondering if you had any thoughts on how to create the attributes of Interval 0 (first timestamp), Interval 1, Interval 2, etc, where the intervals are measured in relation to the Interval 0?

Comment: @LillianMilagrosCarrasquillo: I am not sure I understand your question. I propose you open another question and include examples of what you have and what you want to get exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your input!

I have the realtimes, as above, and want to instead have intervals. For each unique ID/ Cat1/ Cat2 I want to have the first time as "Interval 0" and define Interval 1 as the next realtime1 - realtime 2.